# How to delete events from Google calendar using cURL

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to delete an event from Google calendar using php cURL?
I need an example on how to get the eventid and how to delete. I have done some research and turned out there is a way to do it with "CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST" but I was unable to find any example...

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there an API?

Comment: where did you find? I got [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php) from google calendar api.

Comment: Google provides a PHP client-side library for interacting with its various services, including Calendar.  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ There's a simple example that shows how to use the client library to fiddle with Calendar items.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The google API codes provided by Google require authentication, which won't work for my purpose. I need everyone on my website add/delete events to/from my calendar without authentication and that's why I am using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $calendarId ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com";
    $eventId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';


    $APIKEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';    

    $tokenURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    $postData = array(
        'client_secret'=>'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'grant_type'=>'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token'=>'1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'client_id'=>'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $tokenReturn = curl_exec($ch);
    $token = json_decode($tokenReturn);
    //var_dump($tokenReturn);
    $accessToken = $token->access_token;

    //$token = getAccessToken();
    //echo $token; exit;

    //var_dump($auth);
    $request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendarId . '/events/'.$eventId.'?sendNotifications=true&key=' . $APIKEY;

    $ch = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '. $accessToken)
    );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
     $httpCode = curl_getinfo($response, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $result = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding an explanation to your code.